# How to reverse the order of Angular ngRepeat by object's keys which are numeric

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular JS's `ngRepeat` directive, how can I make it so that the resulting iterations go in the reverse order? I am using an object where the keys are numbers, and I'd like to sort by those, descending.

I know that you can't really sort an object by keys like this (without keeping a reference to an array), but is this at all possible with Angular?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
      return function(items, field, reverse) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
          filtered.push(item);
        });
        filtered.sort(function(a, b) {
          return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
        });
        if (reverse) filtered.reverse();
        return filtered;
      };
    });
    app.controller('myController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
          2013: 'oldest 4',
          2014: 'older 3',
          2015: 'new 2',
          2016: 'newest 1'
        };
      }
    ]);
  </script>
  <div id="myApp" ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="(date,text) in data">{{text}}</div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="(date,text) in data | orderBy:date:reverse">{{text}}</div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="(date,text) in data | orderBy:'-date'">{{text}}</div>
    <hr/>
    <div><b>Correct Answer!:</b></div><hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="(date,text) in data | orderObjectBy:date:true">{{text}}</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

For example, i'd like this to sort from Most recent to Oldest (the opposite of what it does in this code)

Comment: If you want to order by date in reverse order then just put '-' before the field name. So the code will be "(date,text) in data | orderBy:'-date'"

Comment: use filter.. I mean -ng-repeat='(date,text) in data s | orderBy:date:reverse'

Comment: Thanks guys, but I've tried that with the updated code in my question it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Anita you were right but that is only possible for the case of array and Ved yah reverse is a good option but it also only work for array.
You guys can check the issue here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8458

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ng-repeat doen't work with object for it you need to create your custom filter.

```
 <div ng-repeat="(date,text) in data | orderObjectBy:date:true">{{text}}</div>

app.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Actually `ng-repeat` does work with object (i.e. can iterate its properties). It's `orderBy` that cannot sort anything but arrays.